# Bash Script to ssh into a macOS and execute a local script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, osx

I used the following command to initiate a ssh connection to a remote macOS .Objective is to perform successful ssh login and mount a particular network share (via the mount.sh script).The script mount.sh when stored and executed on the remote macOS works fine.The script intakes user inputs and mounts the same into a user defined mount point.But am stuck whenever I would try to locally execute the script-mount.sh on the remote system via ssh.

In fact the ssh login works well but the script-mount.sh doesn't gets executed.

```
 #!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter  Username: " username
    ssh $username@<Server IP> "$(< mount.sh)"
```

Any suggestions/advice to improve the code are welcome :).

The mount.sh script code :

```
    #!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter the name of share mount :" lpmount
echo ""
read -p "Enter your  User name: " username
echo ""
read -p "Enter the year (e.g. 2018,2019) :" year
mkdir /Gross/$lpmount
mount_smbfs //$username@<Server-IP>/Evi/$year /Gross/$lpmount
mount_status=$? # Checks if the mounting was successfull.
if [ $mount_status -eq 0 ]
then
        echo ""
        echo "Share mounted SUCCESSFULLY! at /Gross/$lpmount"
        sleep 3
else
        echo ""
        echo " Share not mounted SUCCESSFULLY! at/Gross/$lpmount"

fi
```

Comment: What is `mount.sh` doing (can you share that script)?

Comment: can you try to run script with `-x` option as that will show where it is failing !!

Comment: My point in getting to know what `mount.sh` is doing is: `mount.sh` could probably do the `ssh` itself as something simple, like `ssh user@server mount ...`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, Agreed. that if `mount.sh` is simple command then it should be passed as `stdin` but just in case it's doing more than just command !!

Comment: You say "the ssh login works well but the script-mount.sh doesn't gets executed". What actually happens when you run the ssh command? Do you get any messages at all? What do the messages say?

Comment: mount_smbfs: mount error:  Operation not permitted

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

You can add `bash -s` onption which will process the script. Please see below Modification:

### Modification:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter  Username: " username
    ssh $username@<Server IP> 'bash -s' < mount.sh
```

Comment: Unbalanced parentheses.